# Creating a dplyr summarised table

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that I'd like to be summarised. My data looks like this [looks like this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zljXN7oxUvij2mXHiyuRVG3xp5063chEFW_QERgHegg/edit?usp=sharing).

The table in Sheet1 refers to the original table.
The table in Sheet2 is the result I'd like to get, using dplyr.

Basically, for each variable (Our Website, Friendliness of Staff, and Food Quality), I'd like a sum of 'Satisfied' + 'Very Satsified', expressed as a percentage of the total number of respondents for the Parameter. For example, the 80% for the Internet Column is 4 (Satisfied+V.Satisfied)/5 (total number of respondents whose moed of reservation is Internet) * 100 = 80%.

I used this code but I'm not getting the desired result:

```
test %>%
     group_by(Parameter.1..Mode.of.reservation,Our.Website) %>% 
     select(Our.Website,Friendliness.of.Staff,Food.Quality) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(freq = n()))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

@ira's solution can be streamlined if you `gather` the data prior to `summarizing`.  This way you skip the multiple assignments.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(googlesheets)
library(scales)

# Authorize with google.
gs_auth()

# Register the sheet
gs_data <- gs_url("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zljXN7oxUvij2mXHiyuRVG3xp5063chEFW_QERgHegg/")

# Read in the first worksheet
data <- gs_read(gs_data, ws = 1) 

# Summarize using tidyr/dplyr
data %>%
  gather(item, response, -1:-2) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(response)) %>% 
  group_by(`Parameter 1: Mode of reservation`, item) %>% 
  summarise(percentage = percent(sum(response %in% c("Satisfied","Very Satisfied"))/n())) %>% 
  spread(`Parameter 1: Mode of reservation`, percentage)
```

Comment: Thank you Jake. But how would you modify the code for a dataset that has missing values? When I use this code for a dataset with missing values, the n() takes into consideration the missing ones as well.

Comment: You would filter out the `na` values ahead of time, right after the `gather` step.  Code has been edited to include this

Comment: Thanks. The code works on the larger dataset with missing values. Would there also be a way to get number of responses per mode of reservation (an additional row below the row with the column headers?)

Answer (score -1):

After using dplyr to summarise the data, you can use tidyr to transpose the dataset so that you have the columns and rows just as you asked in the question.

```
# read in the data
data <- read.csv("C:/RSnips/My Dataset - Sheet1.csv")
# load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# take the loaded data
data2 <- data %>%
        # group it by mode of reservation
        group_by(Parameter.1..Mode.of.reservation) %>%
        # summarise
        summarise(
                # count how many times website column takes values sat or very sat and divide by number of observations in each group given by group_by
                OurWeb = sum(Our.Website == "Satisfied" |
                                      Our.Website == "Very Satisfied")/n(),
                # do the same for Staff and food
                Staff = sum(Friendliness.of.Staff == "Satisfied" |
                                      Friendliness.of.Staff == "Very Satisfied")/n(),
                Food = sum(Food.Quality == "Satisfied" |
                                     Food.Quality == "Very Satisfied")/n()) %>%
        # If you want to have email, internet and phone in columns
        # use tidyr package to transpose the dataset
        # first turn it into a long format, where mode of the original columns are your key
        gather(categories, val, 2:(ncol(data)-1)) %>%
        # then turn it back to wide format, but mode of reservation will be in columns
        spread(Parameter.1..Mode.of.reservation, val)
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
data %>% data
   mutate(OurWebsite2 = ifelse(Our.Website == "Very Satisfied" | Our.Website == "Satisfied", 1, 0),
          Friendlinessofstaff2 = ifelse(Friendlinessofstaff == "Very Satisfied" | Friendlinessofstaff  == "Satisfied", 1, 0),
          FoodQuality2 = ifelse(FoodQuality== "Very Satisfied" | FoodQuality== "Satisfied", 1, 0) %>%
   group_by(Parameter1) %>%
   summarise(OurWebsiteSatisfaction = mean(OurWebsite2),
             FriendlinessofstaffSatisfaction = mean(Friendlinessofstaff2),
             FoodQualitySatisfaction = mean(FoodQuality2))
```